# Windows port forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding, windows-service, daemon

This is the scenario:

- A Windows XP client
- A Linux Server

The client is natted/firewalled/unreacheable from *outside*, the linux server is public.

I need to allow the client, once upon some conditions, to expose the remote desktop port (3389) on the Linux Server, somethig like ssh -R 3389:localhost:3389.

I dream it as a service, or something like that so I can start and stop the *"forwarding-session"* on my needs.

I've to **pilot** this session from some program-language (python or ruby mostly).

Any hint?

*Thanks in advance*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit late, I suppose, but the stunnel project can be used to forward the Windows port 3389 to the Linux box, such that if you open the port on the Linux box you'll actually be connecting to RDP on the Windows box.

http://www.stunnel.org/